# Where do input strings like "1480184563863912448" come from when deleting a record in Solr?

Tags: solr

When performing a `delete` in `Solr`, it keeps failing. Committing new ones still works. I have been unsuccesfull in finding why this happens, different documents/different entries does not seem to make a difference.

The `solr` log keeps giving the error:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "", with different strings, though all the same length and all starting with 14.
```

Whats going on here? Where does this string come from?

Stack trace:

```
auto commit error...:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1480184563863912448"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at org.apache.lucene.queries.function.docvalues.IntDocValues.getRangeScorer(IntDocValues.java:97)
        at org.apache.solr.search.function.ValueSourceRangeFilter$1.iterator(ValueSourceRangeFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.solr.search.SolrConstantScoreQuery$ConstantScorer.<init>(SolrConstantScoreQuery.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrConstantScoreQuery$ConstantWeight.scorer(SolrConstantScoreQuery.java:123)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:356)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.QueryWrapperFilter$1.iterator(QueryWrapperFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.BufferedUpdatesStream.applyQueryDeletes(BufferedUpdatesStream.java:554)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.BufferedUpdatesStream.applyDeletesAndUpdates(BufferedUpdatesStream.java:287)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.applyAllDeletesAndUpdates(IndexWriter.java:3268)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeApplyDeletes(IndexWriter.java:3259)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2973)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3122)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3089)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:582)
    at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.run(CommitTracker.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Schem.xml fields config

```
<fields>                                                                         
<field name="_version_" type="int" indexed="true" />                                          
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
  <field name="content_nl" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
  <field name="title_nl" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />   
  <field name="title_h1_nl" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="root_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />               
  <field name="text" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />       
  <field name="ondertitel" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
  <field name="programma" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
  <field name="documenttype" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="jaar" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />               
  <field name="file" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" />       
  <field name="meta_description_nl" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="published_start" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />      
  <field name="published_end" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />        
  <field name="trefwoord" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValue
  <field name="auteur" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" multiVa
  <field name="opdrachtgever" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" 
  <field name="alltext" type="testedgengrams" indexed="true" stored="true" multiV                          
  <field name="programma_filter" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
  <field name="documenttype_filter" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" /
  <field name="trefwoord_filter" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" mult
  <field name="auteur_filter" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" multiVa
  <field name="opdrachtgever_filter" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true"                                                                       
</fields>                                                                        

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>                                                        

<defaultSearchField>title_nl</defaultSearchField>                                

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>                                          
    <copyField source="*" dest="alltext"/>                                        
    <copyField source="programma" dest="programma_filter"/>                       
    <copyField source="documenttype" dest="documenttype_filter"/>                 
    <copyField source="trefwoord" dest="trefwoord_filter"/>                       
    <copyField source="auteur" dest="auteur_filter"/>                             
    <copyField source="opdrachtgever" dest="opdrachtgever_filter"/>
```

Comment: is it possible to add the code or request which triggered the delete operation ?

Comment: Url: 'solr_url/update?wt=json' 
Post: '<delete><id>2824</id></delete>' 
ContentType: 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'

Comment: Root cause of this exception is that this number is too big for Integer. Could you show schema.xml, solrconfig.xml and example of docs

Comment: Docs I cannot share, however these are just standard pdf files. What part of solrconfig.xml are you interested in? It is too big to include here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fields-definition you have this:

```
<field name="_version_" type="int" indexed="true" />
```

The version field should be a `long` instead of `int` since the version can become quite large. Try to change it to something like

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Be sure to clean the datafolder and do a clean import